# Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Tags: swiftui, getter, swift5

So I have been trying to fix this problem that has been already discussed here for a few times but I cannot seem to truly understand where the issue comes from and how to fix it in my application. Apologies if this one is obvious but I've picked up SwiftUI a week ago.

Basically what I am doing here is that I have a function called `countStrokes()` where I have an array of strings as an input. First of all I convert the array to an int array, then compute the sum of the array and return the sum as a `String`.
After that I declare a new lazy var called `strokes` and initialise it by calling the `countStrokes()` function.
All I want to do in the `View` is to print out the strokes value using the `Text()` module.
Any ideas of how to modify my existing code will be much appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Skore: View {
    @State var skore: [String]

    lazy var strokes: String = countStrokes(array: skore)
    var body: some View {
        Text(strokes)
    }
}

func countStrokes(array: [String]) -> String {
    let newArray = array.compactMap{Int($0)}
    let total = newArray.reduce(0, +)
    let totalString = String(total)

    return totalString
}
```

Comment: Why is it lazy instead of computed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is just use function inline. As soon as your view depends on `skore` state and `countStrokes` depends on it, once `skore` will be modified the corresponding `Text` will be recalculated and shows correct result.

```
struct Skore: View {
    @State var skore: [String]

    var body: some View {
        Text(countStrokes(array: skore))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is this:

```
struct Skore: View {
@State var skore: [String]
@State var strokes: String = ""
var body: some View {
    Text(strokes).onAppear(perform: loadData)
}
func loadData() {
    self.strokes = countStrokes(array: skore)
}
}

func countStrokes(array: [String]) -> String {
let newArray = array.compactMap{Int($0)}
let total = newArray.reduce(0, +)
let totalString = String(total)
return totalString
}

struct ContentView: View {
@State var skore = ["1","2","3"]
var body: some View {
    Skore(skore: skore)
}
}
```